# Forbid linking against a c++ method

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, dependency-walker

I try to forbid the use of a method, to have a compile error if some piece of code use it.

This is a proprietary legacy module, that I know that some methods are problematic. We have headers files, and dlls.

I can't figure out all the use of this method in the huge project I use (lot of defines, some implicit cast...)

Can the compiler stop (or just warn) if it detect the use of this method?

Comment: just remove it from header file? you'll get compilation errors

Comment: Can you modify the source code or at least the header files?

Comment: Maybe just `undef` it?

Comment: Yes I can edit the header file. Remove the declaration don't do anything. The method is just an operator<< for a class, an take a reference for an OStream.

Comment: @saad Maybe the code that uses it uses a different declaraction.
Have you tried declaring it with = delete?

Comment: How did you manage to make a legacy `operator<<` problematic? lol

Comment: This is an old proprietary library, linked with VC7. The code that using it is moving to VC11... :)

Comment: You should think about purchasing a static analysis tool that will continuously check to make sure your developers are following the rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `__declspec(deprecated)` in Visual C++ to generate warnings for use of a specific function. You can use `#pragma deprecated` to deprecate the usage of any symbol (including macros).

See more information [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/044swk7y.aspx). This can generate warnings or errors (depending on computer flags) but you can supress them where needed with additional `#pragma`s

Answer (score 0):

Well, not sure if it works or not (so please correct me), but you might want to play with making libs out of your DLLs

something along the line, from VS command prompt:

```
dumpbin /exports yourdll.dll
```

you'll get export symbols output and copy it into .def file

edit .def file to remove unwanted symbols

make lib and link it to your app

```
lib /def:C:\mydef.def /OUT:C:\mylib.lib
```